# ReactJs undefined is not an Object (evaluating '_examplefunction')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have one JS file called Movies.JS

```
   import * as moviesActions from './movies.actions';
    import CardOne from 'my-test';


    class Movies extends Component {


        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                isLoading: true,
                isRefreshing: false
            };

            this._viewMovie = this._viewMovie.bind(this);
            this._onRefresh = this._onRefresh.bind(this);
            this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this._onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));

         }

        componentWillMount() {
            this._retrieveMovies();
            CardOne.startMovie();
        }

    render() { 
.. more code 
}
```

I imported my own custom library called my-test written in java with ReactMethod, but when i try calling that function is gives me error.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_cardOne.default.startMovies')

It works on other projects but just not this one. Sorry I am new to React Native.

EDIT: Here is my custom library 
my-test

```
package com.my.test;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.util.ReactFindViewUtil;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class CardOne extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ReactFindViewUtil.OnViewFoundListener {

    public CardOne(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        new ReactFindViewUtil().addViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "PointziReact";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void startMovie (String tag){
        // Do some stuff here    
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code the code of `CardOne`, the javascript one. The function `startMovies` is not exported under the default object in `card-react`

Comment: It seems like the library is written with pure JS code https://github.com/shatran/card-react

Comment: sorry for confusion, it is my own library `my-test` please see edit

Comment: I would try to create a NativeModule following this manual: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: @RudolfCicko, thanks but i did follow the manual. It's working on all other apps except for this one.

Comment: Check then for all differences from libraries version to functions. Because you are implementing an interface be careful also if is not missing a method or something. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_cardOne.default.startMovies')

means i forgot to import my library in android/app MainApplication.

```
Add import my.test.library.CardOne to the imports at the top of the file
Add new myTestPackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method
```